# Hide and show text on webpage according login status

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I want lo show some button on webpage according login status of user in mvc view page.

I'm using ajax function to check login status of user then according that button hide and show.

since page got load before ajax response come.it seem odd to hide and show button on after page page load

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.IsuserLogin == "true") {
                $("#withlogin").show();
                $("#notlogin").hide();

            } else {
                $("#withlogin").hide();
                $("#notlogin").show();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Is there any way to call ajax function first take response then load page.

i'm already calling ajax function at time document ready function.

Comment: Can't you just output the user code inside your .net code? using ajax might not work if somehow (in rare chases) they disable javascript.

Comment: yes, try to put same logic in controller's action and set IsuserLogin in ViewBag and use it in View

Comment: actually issue what i'm facing is my external and user account site is running at two domain and i am not using database at external site.. so by ajax function is function in user account action

Answer (score 0):

So what if you put this in your page and display appropriate text based upon if request is authenticated or not.

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
<div> Authenticated</div>
}else{
<div>Anonymous </div>
}
```